# Modification to an ASP page are not taken into account

Tags: asp-classic

I have to modify an old application made in what I believe to be pre .NET ASP (I am a Java programmer, I don't usually program in ASP so I am not sure).

I found the page I need to modify and modified it but my modifications are not taken into account.

I think I need to do something to force a recompile of the application but I do not know what.

The application in question is deployed on a Windows 2003 server if it matters.

Comment: there is no need to compile asp pages, probably it is cache or you altered wrong page

Comment: Asp pages does not need to be compiled. Make sure that the file is in the correct location after modifying it and try clearing your cookies/cache on your browsers.

Comment: Verify your browser is not serving up the old files from cache.

Comment: If it's classic asp then the file should have the extension ".asp".

Comment: The page in question, a .asp page, is part of the login process of the site so I assumed they made sure it is not cached but I will check on Monday. I assumed the directory I modified was the right one as I am more an Apache guy than an IIS guy but I will try to check the IIS server config to make sure. Thank you!

Comment: No cache for those things, you edited wrong file (or in wrong place). In the IIS Management Console (inetmgr command line) check the properties of the site, it should also contain physical location on the disk.

Comment: I was able to fix some problems but now I again have the same problem after that server was migrated from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008. The application was apparently automagically transferred to IIS 7 and it looks like this line 'Set rsProjects = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")" now fails... I tried replacing it with "Set rsProjects = Conn.Execute(strSQL, , &H1)" (strSQL contains the SQL to run) but I still get CreateObjects errors... The only place where I can see those errors is in Event Viewer????